# Task scheduling function in python and using the sched library in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, scheduled-tasks, job-scheduling

I created a task scheduling function in python and using the **sched** library and used the **sch.enterabs** () function to schedule several functions, and it executes several functions at a certain time for each one, but if the first function takes a long time executing, the next one will wait for the first one to finish and will not work at the scheduled time. I wanted it to work when the time came, regardless of the first being completed, someone help me?

The Schedule code

```
def schedule_with_properties():
    sch = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)


    hh = "09"
    mm = "10"
    ss = 52
    ninute = mm - 1


    t1 = (2020, 4, 1, int(hh), int(ninute), ss, 1, 48, 0)
    t2 = (2020, 4, 1, 9, 15, ss, 1, 48, 0)
    t2 = (2020, 4, 1, 9, 20, 0, 1, 48, 0)
      
    time_sec = time.mktime(t1) 
    time_sec2 = time.mktime(t2) 
    time_sec3 = time.mktime(t3) 

    sch.enterabs(time_sec, 0, buyDigital, ())
    sch.enterabs(time_sec2, 1, buyDigital, ())
    sch.enterabs(time_sec3, 2, buyDigital, ())
    sch.run()
```

Comment: Why not use celery?

Comment: The `python` interpreter doesn't perform preemptive multitasking when using modules like `sched`. You'll have to use something like `celery` as @ShreeRangaRaju suggests or take things into your own hands with `async`, `multiprocessing` or `threading`.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, keep using a "sched" library and use the threading as suggested, that way, when the time comes, it creates a new thread for that event so no event interferes with any other, thankful

Comment: @ShreeRangaRaju selery was not going to help much in what I intend to do, I just wanted a small code snippet for that

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the halp, i keptusing the `sched` library and use the `threading` as suggested, that way, when the time comes, it creates a new `thread` for that event so no event interferes with any other, in that way

```
job = []

file= open('list.txt', 'r')

for line in arquivo:
    Ent = 10
    time = "10:00"
    Par = line[3:9]
    Dur = line[1:2]
    Dir = line[19:22]
    x = threading.Thread(target=run, args=(Ent,Par,Dir,Dur,time))
    job.append(x)

for j in job:
        j.start()
```

the run method

```
def run(Ent,Par,Dir,Dur,time):
        sch.enterabs(Hora, 1, someMethod, (Ent,Par,Dir,Dur,time))
    sch.run()



def someMethod(Ent,Par,Dir,Dur,time):
   ......
```